# Send Location updates in every 30 minutes when gps enabled

Tags: android, gps, sms

Hi I am fetch my code here. i want send location updates through sms in every 30 minutes when gps enable. Now my problem is this code send sms sequencialy. so, i want use thread here. how to use thread? any one help me.

```
 protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;

@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.autocapture);  
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

}  



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lati = location.getLatitude();
    double longi = location.getLongitude();
    final String l_lati = String.valueOf(lati).trim();
    final String l_longi = String.valueOf(longi).trim();
    sendSMS(l_lati,l_longi);

}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    Log.d("Latitude","disable");
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    Log.d("Latitude","enable"); 
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    Log.d("Latitude","status");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything in particular to add the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your onCreate block with this coding,

```
@Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.autocapture);  

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 60 * 1000, 0, this);

        sendSMS();
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to set `long minTime` parameter to 30 minutes, then you will get updates every 30 minutes.
Here:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Instead of 0 you must set 30 * 60 * 1000.

Please look at documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener)